Plotting two time series that have data on different dates
Plotting two time series in R that have data on different dates. The series overlap, however using ggplot does not produce overlapping series.
I have run this code:
library(ggplot2)

## minimal dataset to create a graph
merged_suprises <- data.frame(
date = c("1997-10-01", "1997-10-09", "1997-11-06","1997-11-12","1997-12-04","1998-01-01"),
RR = c(0,NA,NA,NA,NA,0.22),
FSScm1 = c(NA, 0.030, 0.15,-0.04, -0.03,NA),
SON3c1 = c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA)
)

scale_factor <- max(merged_suprises$RR,na.rm=TRUE) / max(merged_suprises$FSScm1,na.rm = TRUE)

ggplot(merged_suprises, aes(x = date)) +
  # Primary y-axis line
  geom_line(aes(y = RR, color = "RR")) +
  # Secondary y-axis line, scaled down
  geom_line(aes(y = FSScm1 * scale_factor, color = "FSScm1")) +
  geom_line(aes(y = SON3c1 * scale_factor, color = "SON3c1" )) +
  # Primary y-axis scale
  scale_y_continuous(name = "Romer Romer Shock (blue)",
                     # Define secondary axis
                     sec.axis = sec_axis(~ . / scale_factor, name = "HFI Shock (red)")) +
  # Set colors for lines
  scale_color_manual(name = "Legend", values = c("RR" = "blue", "FSScm1" = "red", "SON3c1" = "dark red")) +
  theme_minimal() +
  labs(x = "Date",title = "Monetary Policy Shock Series") +
  theme(
    axis.title.y.left = element_text(color = "blue"),
    axis.title.y.right = element_text(color = "red"),
    legend.position = "top",
    plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5) 
  )


Which yielded this graph:

There should be overlapping series of FSScm1 and RR. I think the reason may be because the observations I have for the two time series occur on different dates and thus there are discontinuities in the red and blue series.
My desired output would be two series with MP and FSScm1 that are overlapping between 1997 and 2007. The SON3c1 series is okay.
In this case, ggplot doesn't plot anything when using the code above, yet I would like it to have a series for FSScm1 and a series for RR and no series for SON3c1.

It would help to provide an example of the data that isn't plotting as you expect. Could you run dplyr::filter(merged_suprises, date > as.Date("1996-01-01"), date < as.Date("2004-01-01")) |> dput()? or is that a huge amount of data? I get the impression that you might have segments where both series have duplicate x values, such that the segments are 100% overlapped. If you want to see both, you might use some alpha or jitter the lines slightly. I suspect there could be a data issue upstream that is leading to odd results starting around year 1998.

RR = c(0,NA,NA,NA,NA,0.22) means that no line gets drawn. You can't connect 0 to NA and you can't connect NA to 0.22. You could try geom_line(aes(y = RR, color = "RR"), \(d) tidyr::drop_na(d, RR)), and similar for the other lines.

@Axeman This solved my problem, thank you so much.
